# Recursive CTE with Offset Row for Metadata From Information_Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, information-schema

I have a multi-lingual database set up (it's actually more complicated than that - but I'm keeping it simple). The translateable data is put in a table called `Fact`. The data is linked to from a table called `FactLink` (with only a single column called `FactLinkID`. It is being referenced to by multiple columns in a table. But sometimes the `FactLink` table can be referenced indirectly when the data makes up it's own set. E.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE FactLink
( FactLinkID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) Primary KEY
)

CREATE TABLE [Language]
( LanguageID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) Primary KEY
, Code varchar(50) not null
)

CREATE TABLE Fact
( FactLinkID INT NOT NULL
, LanguageID INT NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FactLinkID ASC, LanguageID ASC)
, CONSTRAINT fk_Fact_FactLinkID FOREIGN KEY (FactLinkID) REFERENCES dbo.FactLink (FactLinkID)
, CONSTRAINT fk_Fact_LanuageID FOREIGN KEY (LanguageID) REFERENCES dbo.[Language] (LanguageID)
)

CREATE TABLE LimitedTranslateableItem
( LimitedTranslateableItemID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, [Order] INT NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT fk_LimitedTranslateableItem_Table1ID FOREIGN KEY (LimitedTranslateableItemID) REFERENCES dbo.FactLink (FactLinkID)
)

CREATE TABLE [All]
( AllID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
, TranslateableItemID INT NOT NULL
, LimitedTranslateableItemID INT NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT fk_All_TranslateableItemID FOREIGN KEY (TranslateableItemID) REFERENCES dbo.FactLink (FactLinkID)
, CONSTRAINT fk_All_LimitedTranslateableItemID FOREIGN KEY (LimitedTranslateableItemID) REFERENCES dbo.LimitedTranslateableItem (LimitedTranslateableItemID)
)
```

I would like to get all the columns that reference the `FactLink` table whether directly or indirectly. Getting the direct links is easy. I figure I need to get the indirect links through a `Recursive CTE`. But I'm not sure how to do that. I'm new to `Recursive CTE`s. So that is part of the problem But also, the reference to the `FactLink` constraint is in a different row than the matching constraint.

```
-- Get constraint for FactLink table
DECLARE @FactLinkPKConstraint sysname
SELECT @FactLinkPKConstraint = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'FactLink'
  AND t.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

SELECT
      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , t.COLUMN_NAME
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'All'
  AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
  AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = @FactLinkPKConstraint
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , t.COLUMN_NAME
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'All'
  AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
UNION ALL
SELECT
      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , t.COLUMN_NAME
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (
    SELECT ct.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM CTE ct
    WHERE ct.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME <> @FactLinkPKConstraint)
  --AND t.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT c.TABLE_NAME FROM CTE c)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE t
```

Of course, it doesn't work since the `Recursive CTE` can't be reference in a sub query. And it doesn't get me the row with the match to the `FactLink` table constraint.

Maybe when I sleep on this I have it figured out. But some pointers would help.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

This is the best I could come up with. It doesn't fit exactly in my criteria but is actually a little better since it finds even more depedencies than I originally planned for. This will get the `FactLink` columns of a table that the `All` table also references.

```
;WITH AFactLinkPKConstraint AS (
SELECT t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'FactLink'
  AND t.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
), APrimary AS (
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
WHERE t.CONSTRAINT_NAME IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
        ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'All' )
)
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    AND rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = (SELECT pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM AFactLinkPKConstraint pk)
JOIN APrimary p
    ON p.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
    AND p.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the two **Scenario** that i have tested:

**Without using cte:**

```
  DECLARE @FactLinkPKConstraint sysname
  SELECT @FactLinkPKConstraint = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t
  WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'FactLink'
  AND t.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'


 SELECT
      TABLE_SCHEMA
    , TABLE_NAME
    , CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , COLUMN_NAME
    , UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME from

 (SELECT
      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , t.COLUMN_NAME
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'All'
  AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
UNION ALL
SELECT
      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , t.COLUMN_NAME
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME) as result
WHERE UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME =@FactLinkPKConstraint
  --AND t.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT c.TABLE_NAME FROM CTE c)
```

**Using cte:**

```
  DECLARE @FactLinkPKConstraint sysname
  SELECT @FactLinkPKConstraint = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS t
  WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'FactLink'
  AND t.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'

 ;with cte as
 (
    select @FactLinkPKConstraint  as col1
 ),
 FactLinkPKConstraint as 
 (
    select * from cte
 ),result as
 (

 SELECT
      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , t.COLUMN_NAME
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME = 'All'
  AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
UNION ALL
SELECT
      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    , t.COLUMN_NAME
    , rc.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    ON rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = t.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 )
 select * from result where UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = (select col1 from FactLinkPKConstraint) 

  --AND t.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT c.TABLE_NAME FROM CTE c)
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to tackle this problem. But your solution will grab all references to `@FactLinkPKConstraint`. That is, if another table, let's say `All2` references `@FactLinkPKConstraint` then it will grab those also. I need them to only grab the columns from `All` that reference `@FactLinkPKConstraint` or if one of it's sub tables reference it.